# Javascript + Base 64 encoding the answer for me?

Tags: javascript, base64

Background:

I have a (.php) form...

Simple HTML and Javascript validation..etc..

On a couple of fields... I have an onChange and onKeyUp function to call a .js function:

```
onKeyUp="dothemath()" 
onChange="dothemath()"
```

It was requested to make an update to this form, to allow for a 'discount code' to be applied.

The issue I am facing, is:

If I add this discount variable to the form as a .js var...

Anyone will be able to see it in the source code.. (and hence get the discount)

If I only do this check/validation server side (.php).. the previous form state does NOT update and display the correct amount the user would need to pay.

After some searching.. I cam across Base 64 Encoding as a possible solution.

I get the 'basic understanding' of it..  you have a variable/text/string (whatever).. that you pass to a base 64 encoding function.. and it gives you an encoded result..   doing vice versa gives you back your original string/data...

My disconnect comes into play on HOW to implement this.. while still keeping things 'protected'  (for lack of a better word) in the source code?

I guess I'm fuzzy on how it all works together?

Should this 'Base 64 Encoding' function/code live in an external file? or something similar?  How will I pass the data back and forth within the form then?

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree here?  Is there a better/alternate solution to be used here?  I really dont want have a ton of work here..  its one field.. and one discount code..

but want to be as secure/clean as possible too.

Comment: Base64 is an *encoding* not *encryption*. Even if you encoded the discount anyone can just decode it. You will have to do server side authentication and use AJAX to update the form.

Comment: If you want this discount code to be hidden, you should find a way to not put it in your javascript source that runs in the browser. Base64 encoding is not a way to hide sensitive information. The algorithm is easily reversible by design.

Comment: You should do the coupon check on the server. You can use AJAX to make the form show the new price quickly after the code is entered.

Comment: the above comments are true, but i bet base64 would stop 99% of visitors from stealing a coupon code via view-source; most real-world users don't even know what JavaScript is, much less base64...

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys..   I guess Base 64 was -not- the droids....err...solution I was looking for!  :)

@AgentME

The only problem with that is,.. the form 'updates' to display the current/correct price BEFORE the form is submitted  (it collects CC# data as well in same form, before submission)

Comment: ajax could work to update the form values _before_ submit()ing the form...

Comment: @dandavis

(my manager had suggested it, so I am trying to follow up on it, see if its a viable answer)...

99% of people (blocked) would be better then 0 :)

My question though (if I still followed this approach) is HOW do I do this then?  If I have the Base 64 Encoding 'functions' in the same form/js block...  it wont be much different than just hard coding the value in the file itself....   no?

Comment: in the js file: `var discountCode=atob("Y3V0MTA=");` to make that encoded value, look at the output of `btoa("cut10")` in a js console. again, not quite as good as a server-side validation, but far simpler (code-wise) and it's much faster to validate w/o the round trip. if an occasional un-deserved discount won't run you out of business, it's a simple approach. besides, i like to reward nerds...

Comment: @dandavis

So if I understand....

(not real experienced with AJAX, so bare with me as I walk through it)

when the 'field' is being updated.. (onKeyUp or onChange)...

I call an 'AJAX' function.. that reaches out to a ...??  (.php script) does the checking of field value against hardcoded var in .php script, and then returns either a new value or not for the AJAX return/handler to update a field with?

Comment: for an ajax approach, use the `oninput` event on inputs, but the rest looks good, and shouldn't take more the a few hours to get working by altering basic js/php ajax interaction examples. on the right track.

Comment: Get the user input , post the input to server then run backend validation against input . This way your users will only get promo code if validation is passed on server side . Just return a temp promo code for each successful response . Maybe even attach a time stamp or uid to each promo code ...just an idea .. server side validation will eliminate base64 .

Comment: If dandavis (or anyone) wants to post something as an answer..  I'll accept it.  I believe both approaches have given me a direction and clarification.

* still not 100% clear on how to implement the Base64 approach though..?

Just a function at top?.. and if this was in the file? "Y3V0MTA="

Couldnt they just decode it?  (just want to make sure I fully understand is all)

Guess I'm off to read up on some AJAX?